# Basic pause/resume functionality in C++

Tags: c++, system

I am making a primitive time keeper that I would like to pause and resume with the simple press of a key. I've been told that

```
system("pause>null")
```

pauses the program until a key is hit, but how is the conditional written to pause to begin with?

Preferred structure in pseudo-code:

```
if (certain_key_pressed)
{
    pause_program_until_any_key_hit;
}
```

Comment: pause>null will be OS dependant. Have you looked at the standard IO methods to see what exists that will basically do you pseudo code "as is" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate "Press any key to continue?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449324/how-to-simulate-press-any-key-to-continue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 idioms to choose from here. Polling or event driven programming.

Polling is the more simple but often less elegant solution where the program would periodically check to see if the pause button has been hit within a loop.

```
While(not_quit)
{
    if(key_pressed)
        Etc...
```

In event driven programming, you would register the pauseButtonPressed event with an event handler. When the pause button is pressed, a special function assigned the task of handling the event would call the pause function.

Comment: The event driven style will fit my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( certain_key_pressed )
    while ( true )
    {
        if ( any_key_hit )
            break;
    }
```

Something like this would suspend any loop it is placed in (presumably your program loop) when the particular key is pressed. It would then keep it suspended until any key is hit.