# How to cause my C++ program to wait for sensor events for ever and not terminate

Tags: c++, windows, sensors

I'm trying to write a simple C++ app that registers to Windows sensor events.
I followed the MSDN documentaion and managed succesfully to get notifications when sensor events occur, my problem is that my main function ends, and so does the application.
How to i cuase it to wait forever for events to occur? Currently it registers and dies...

I have the following code:

My main looks like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   RegisterToSensorEvents();
   return 0;
}

void RegisterToSensorEvents()
{
    ISensorManager* pSensorManager = NULL;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SensorManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSensorManager));

    // Get a collection of all sensors on the computer.
    ISensorCollection* pSensorCollection = NULL;
    hr = pSensorManager->GetSensorsByCategory(SENSOR_CATEGORY_ALL, &pSensorCollection);

    EventsManager *pEventClass = NULL;
    ISensorEvents* pMyEvents = NULL;
    pEventClass = new(std::nothrow) EventsManager();   
    hr = pEventClass->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMyEvents));

    ULONG numOfSensors;
    pSensorCollection->GetCount(&numOfSensors);
    for(int i=0; i< numOfSensors; i++)
    {
        ISensor *sensor = NULL;
        pSensorCollection->GetAt(i,&sensor);
        hr = sensor->SetEventSink(pMyEvents);
    }
}
```

EventsManager is a class that derives from ISensorEvents and implements its callbacks, for example:

```
STDMETHODIMP EventsManager::OnDataUpdated(ISensor *pSensor,ISensorDataReport *pNewData)
{
    cout  <<"got here: Data Update" << endl;
}
```

I tried:

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
   RegisterToSensorEvents();
   while(true){}
   return 0;
 }
```

but seems like this infinte loop did not leave time for the program to process the incomming events, I tried adding Sleep in the loop body, but it didn't work either.

anyone?

**UPDATE:**

after investigation i see that the issue is different - seems like somehow my registartion of SetEventSink gets canceled and that is why i don't get any event notification.

if i copy this line:
`hr = sensor->SetEventSink(pMyEvents);` into my loop:

```
while(true)
{
   hr = sensor->SetEventSink(pMyEvents);
}
```

the events are fired as expected. But it sounds to me very wrong to do such a thing.

Need to understand why this is hapenning.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're forgetting the [Windows message event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: can you provide the exact code cause infinite loop to not giving proper time to your code to execute something? Because infinite loop is the solution for not ending program.

Comment: How do you actually use the Windows message event loop?

Comment: Is RegisterToSensorEvents a well known function of some library (I don't find it on Google) ? Otherwise you should provide more info on it. Is it starting a thread or something ? Otherwise, here, your infinite loop is not doing anything, not even reading events so there's no chance your program can do anything !

Comment: added the code of my RegisterToSensorEvents function, the problem is not in code since i see it gets invoked if i debug with breakpoints, i'm just looking for something i need to add to my main so it won't terminate

Comment: @AchmadJP: no, it really isn't - or at least not a good one.  Why waste all those CPU cycles?  If you really want to stop dead and not do anything, you should use `Sleep(INFINITE)` instead.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x

Comment: As Joachim said, **you need a message loop.**  COM won't work without one.  I think a call to `MessageBox` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you launch a new thread to do the listening, and just have the main function wait for an input?

[How to simulate "Press any key to continue?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449324/how-to-simulate-press-any-key-to-continue)

[Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)

You can combine these to get your desired result.

Comment: my main now looks like this:
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 std::thread registerToSensor(RegisterToSensor);
 registerToSensor.join();
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
and it is still not working - the event gets fired a few times and that's it, once my program reaches the pause, events stop

Comment: Does it actually exit?

Comment: no, it just wait there for an input, but events are not fired

Comment: Where does it actually hook the event listener?