# Sensor API's SetEventSink() for Windows Console Application

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, com, windows-10

I currently am using asynchronous callback to get the motion data through Window's Sensor API. For now I want to test the functionalities through a Windows 10 Console application (NOT a Windows Application). To simplify things, I am currently having the exact same problem as [How to cause my C++ program to wait for sensor events for ever and not terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693507/how-to-cause-my-c-program-to-wait-for-sensor-events-for-ever-and-not-terminate), where

`while(true) { hr = sensor->SetEventSink(pMyEvents); }` fires the event and I get consistent data, but the proper usage should be just

`hr = sensor->SetEventSink(pMyEvents);`, which will trigger the event asynchronously.

I also used `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);` to allow multithreading in COM.

In the comments in the above SO link, two users mention that "You're forgetting the Windows message event loop." I do not want to have a graphical interface for this program, and more importantly I do not get why "COM will not work without a message loop." This seems to apply only for Windows Application Projects. Could someone elaborate on this, and how to properly use `SetEventSink(ISensorEvent)` to keep receiving the data for a regular console application?

I have confirmed that other code such as for initialization/decoding dataworks by using the synchronous method - `GetData()`.

Comment: Sensor stuff works in the same thread, so COM needs messages to route the calls.

Comment: [Processes, Threads, and Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/processes--threads--and-apartments).

Comment: Yes, it says that for single threaded apartment, "all COM objects are synchronized with the windows message queue." But it says that if we `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`, which makes it a multithreaded apartment, now it is not bound to the windows message queue - free-threaded - so we can simply make everything work with a console application without the Win32Application limitations. So what are some reasons or fixes to why COM Event firing won't work as expected? Please let me know if I am misundertsanding any of the COM related concepts.

Comment: Also it says that "Threads in multi-threaded apartments should not perform UI actions." because "this is because UI threads require a message pump, and COM does not pump messages for threads in a multi-threaded apartment." Does a console application count as a GUI, which leads to must I make ithe eventhandler multithreaded to receive any results?

Comment: You need to get a grip on some fundamentals: `1` The author of a COM object decides, which apartment the object can be instantiated in. You cannot arbitrarily choose. `2` *Any* thread can have a message queue. A thread that owns windows always does, but a GUI is not a requirement. A console application's threads can (or must, in the case of an STA) pump messages. `3` Learn what a [mcve] is, and provide one.